# Выходит ошибка при установке библиотеки pyinstaller Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

```
D:\Python>pip install pyinstaller
```

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\женя\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\женя\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\2CE9~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbpghmf14'
         cwd: C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2oof10c6\pyinstaller
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\ЖЕНЯ\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-52rm5o9o\PyInstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\женя\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\женя\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\2CE9~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbpghmf14' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: pip install wheel

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте изменить имя пользователя в настройках своего компьютера, символы кириллицы вызывают ошибку в pyinstaller